# Backup Trouble same drive mounted to / and /backups with RSYNC

Tags: mount, backup, rsync

So I'm getting a root partition as full after some errors. Here is what I'm seeing.

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sdb1       175G  175G     0 100% /
    none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev            7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
    tmpfs           1.6G  1.4M  1.6G   1% /run
    none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
    none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
    overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
```

As you can see here. I kind of know what happened. I migrated my server to new hardware. My backup USB drive changed UUIDs. I was tired and put the wrong one. So the root drive mounted to / and /backups. When the RSYNC job ran to backup I'm sure it was one hell of a loop. I get what happened but what I can't figure out for the life of me is how to recover these files. I've since taken that part out of my `/etc/fstab` file. Then removed the backups directory. I've ran all kinds of things like NCDU, `df -h`, etc and I cannot find where these "double" files would've be. It's the only thing I can think of that may have caused this.  Again I can't find these double files anywhere but my disk is showing as full so they must be somewhere....Any help or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ncdu
```

should have shown you where the problem was.

Have you tried booting from a live usb like sysrescuecd or grml, so the system is offline, then mounting the root partition and checking with ncdu.

Answer (score 0):

You could dump your whole file tree to a file, then have a look in a text editor, or even a spreadsheet at 10% zoom, to see where parts might appear to duplicated or recursive.

```
find . -type d -name /\* > wholetree.txt
```